# Spyder error connecting to Kernel after performing Pip install of package

Tags: python, conda, ipython, spyder

I get this error:
I cannot figure out what the issue is! Please help, thanks. Using Spyder 5.4.3

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 24, in
start.main()
File "C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 293, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 51, in
from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
File "C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 19, in
from .comm.comm import BaseComm
File "C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\comm\__init__.py", line 3, in
from .comm import Comm
File "C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\comm\comm.py", line 14, in
from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
ImportError: cannot import name 'Kernel' from 'ipykernel.kernelbase' (C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 24, in
start.main()
File "C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 293, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 51, in
from .ipkernel import IPythonKernel
File "C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 19, in
from .comm.comm import BaseComm
File "C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\comm\__init__.py", line 3, in
from .comm import Comm
File "C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\comm\comm.py", line 14, in
from ipykernel.kernelbase import Kernel
ImportError: cannot import name 'Kernel' from 'ipykernel.kernelbase' (C:\Users\maher\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py)
```

I have tried reinstalling both Python and Spyder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this error occur when you try to run some particular code in Spyder, or when trying to start Spyder itself? How did you install Python and Spyder? What's the package you installed with pip and was everything working OK before you installed it? Did you install the package into your base Python environment or did you create a new environment for it, e.g. with conda? We need all this information to help you.